# Gehen Deutsche sorglos mit ihrer Sprache um?

Tags: phrase, spelling

Ich habe fortlaufend das Gefühl, dass in Deutschland nicht so sehr auf die Korrektheit der Sprache geachtet wird; auch an öffentlichen Orten und in den Medien werden (manchmal bewusst) Fehler gemacht. Ich möchte anhand einiger Beispiele illustrieren, was ich meine.

**1.** Gestern in einem kleinen Supermarkt, während eines sage und schreibe 2-minütigen Einkaufs entdeckte ich gleich drei Rechtschreibfehler:

> Kaufen Sie ein, wir **bringens** heim. (*fehlender Apostroph*)
>
> Imbißangebote (*Alte Rechtschreibung*)
>
> Schinken Sandwich (*Deppenleerzeichen*)

**2.** Selbst seriöse, staatliche Universitäten geben sich bewusst fehlerhafte Namen, wie die [Leibniz Universität](https://www.uni-hannover.de/).

**3.** Das Deppenleerzeichen begegnet uns zudem [überall in der Werbung und in den Produktnamen.](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/), z.B. diese tolle [Werbung](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2016/06/25/keine-roaming-lycamobile/) *Keine Roaming / Gebühren in 18 Ländern*

**4.** Falsch benutzter Apostroph ist ebenso ein [weit verbreitetes Problem](http://www.deppenapostroph.info/).

**5.** Selbst in guten Zeitschriften und im Fernsehen, wo man meinen könnte, da sitzt jemand und achtet auf die sprachliche Korrektheit, hört man alle nasenlang fehlerhaftes Deutsch:

- Andauernde falsche Benutzung von [*bzw.*](http://blog.florianheinle.de/post/36346523293/zur-verwendung-von-beziehungsweise)
- Unwörter, wie [*nichtsdestotrotz*](http://www.welt.de/debatte/kolumnen/wortgefecht/article2464585/Nichtsdestotrotz-Ein-Unwort-kommt-selten-allein.html)
- offensichtlich falsche Ausdrücke, Redewendungen, Phrasen wie *Mund-zu-Mund-Propaganda*, *vorprogrammiert* u.Ä.

Was ich damit meine - in dem Land, aus dem ich komme, wäre so etwas undenkbar. Besonders die Medien und die Literatur spielen doch eine große Rolle in der sprachlichen Bildung der Gesellschaft - warum wird hier in Deutschland so sehr geschlampt?

Oder ist es nur mein Eindruck...?

Comment: Warum denkst du, dass solche Fehler "manchmal bewusst" gemacht werden?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2006/07/03/uni-hannover-alle-einwande-und-bedenken-sind-geklart/

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Ich denke, er bezieht sich auf die Werbung. z.B. "Hier werden Sie geholfen"...

Comment: @tofro das natürlich auch, doch das Beispiel mit der Uni finde ich am krassesten.

Comment: Ist es sehr gemein, wenn ich anmerke, dass "[Apostroph](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Apostroph)" maskulin und nicht neutral ist? ;) Also z. B. "fehlender Apostroph" statt "fehlendes" Apostroph".

Comment: Nein, es ist nicht gemein, es ist sehr hilfreich. Danke.

Comment: Außerdem ist es mMn auch eine Frage der Perspektive. Eine Fremdsprache hat man meist gezielt gelernt, inklusive der zur Zeit des Lernens etablierten Regeln dieser Sprache. Deshalb erscheinen einem diese Regeln relativ wichtig und unveränderlich - "*das* ist Englisch, *das* ist Französisch, *das* ist Japanisch und nichts anderes!". Verstöße gegen die Regeln fallen sehr auf. Die eigene Muttersprache verwendet man täglich seit Jahren und Jahrzehnten, und hat viele kleine Veränderungen mitgemacht. Außerdem lernt man die Muttersprache anders. Da erscheinen die formalen Regeln viel weniger wichtig.

Comment: Und auch hier muss ich widersprechen. Deutsch spreche ich schon seit langem zu 99% auf Muttersprachlerniveau und auch in meiner Muttersprache haben mich zahlreiche Fehler genauso irritiert. Doch in den Medien und auf Schildern ist der Sprachgebrauch stets korrekt, da achtet man wesentlich mehr auf die Rechtschreibung und auf die Grammatik, als es hierzulande der Fall ist. Das fällt mir sehr auf!

Comment: Die Frage führt viele Beispiele an, von denen nicht gesagt ist, dass sie überhaupt auf eine gemeinsame Ursache zurückgehen. Da manche Leute auf eine gute Sprache achten und andere nicht ist es auch kaum ein einheitlicher Trend. Die Frage betrifft Kultur und Psychologie und ist vielleicht nach großen, soziologischen Studien zu beantworten - hier dürfte sie nur zu ausufernden Diskussionen führen und muss daher geschlossen werden. Im Chat findest Du vielleicht Anregungen.

Answer (score 8):

Natürlich gehen die Deutschen (wie im übrigen jedes Land in jeder Sprache, ausser ein paar Ausnahmen wie die Franzosen, die aber in den letzten Jahren auch "sorgloser" geworden sind) *sorglos* mit ihrer Sprache um - Und zwar schon seit sie existiert. Ganz einfach deswegen, weil man sich um Sprache keine Sorgen machen muss...

Man sollte akzeptieren, dass Sprache nicht alleine dasteht und "für alle Ewigkeit in Stein gemeisselt" ist, sondern ein Werkzeug darstellt, das einen Zweck, nämlich den eines Transportmittels für Kommunikation erfüllen muss. Wenn sich der Zweck ändert, weil sich die Kommunikationsbedürfnisse der Sprachnutzer (tatsächlich oder "künstlich" - wie bei Werbung) ändern, dann wird sich eben auch das Werkzeug verändern. Manche dieser Änderungen werden in der Sprache Fuss fassen, weil sie allgemein angenommen werden, manche eben nicht und wieder vergessen.

Wenn die "Sprachbewahrer" sich immer durchsetzen würden, würden wir heute immer noch das Deutsch aus der Lutherbibel benutzen. Jedem, der die "Verwahrlosung der deutschen Sprache" beklagt, empfehle ich dringend, darin mal ein paar Kapitel zu lesen. Er wird dort mit Sicherheit auch ein paar "Deppenleerzeichen" finden:

Hesekiel 13:

> ...Ich will einen wind würbel stürmen lassen in meinem grim und einen platz regen in meinem zorn...

Sprache funktioniert ganz klar nach dem Prinzip von *Angebot und Nachfrage* - geschrieben wird, weil es gelesen werden soll, gesprochen wird, damit zugehört wird. Entspricht das Angebot nicht dem Bedürfnis des Lesers/Zuhörers (z.B. weil alles klein oder mit grausiger Rechtscheibung geschrieben ist), wird der "Nachfrager" das "Sprachprodukt" nicht annehmen. Also schreibt der "Sender" i.A. so, wie es die "Empfänger" erwarten.

Werbung und Reklame macht allerdings, um aufzufallen, oft das Gegenteil und möchte durch Nichteinhaltung von Regeln Aufmerksamkeit erregen. Dass das funktioniert, sieht man ja an deiner Frage...

Comment: Interessante Meinung, danke.

Comment: Doch wie gesagt, vieles davon ist offensichtlich falsch (warum sagen "Mund-zu-Mund-Propaganda", wenn "Mundpropaganda" kürzer ist und korrekt; wieso "nichtsdestotrotz", wo doch "trotzdem" kürzer und schöner ist; wieso "bzw." anstatt eines schlichten "und"? Was bringt es, zu schreiben "für's Geld" ("für es Geld"?!), wo "fürs Geld" weniger Tastendrücke benötigt? Ein Teil deiner Argumentation trifft also nicht direkt zu.

Comment: @BarthZalewski Natürlich gibt es (und wird es immer geben) Sprachnutzer, die "Fehler" (d.h. Anwendung von Sprache ausserhalb der derzeit geltenden Regeln) machen, weil sie es einfach nicht besser wissen. Werden sie lange genug für ihr Ladenschild belächelt oder kritisiert, werden sie es wohl ändern - oder auch nicht. Ich nehme nicht an, dass du eine Sprachpolizei einführen willst, die durch die Strassen geht und Strafzettel verteilt.

Comment: Übrigens argumentiere ich nirgendwo mit "Kürze" oder "Einfachheit", wenn du das annimmst, hast du meine Antwort nicht richtig gelesen. Es geht um die Erfüllung einer Erwartungshaltung. Und: Was heute noch als "falsch" gilt, kann morgen schon "richtig" sein - Siehe Aufnahme des sog. "Deppenapostrophen" in den Duden als "erlaubt in gewissen Fällen". Sprache "lebt" eben.

Comment: @Gerhard Ein ganz klares Nein, Kurzform für *für das* ist *fürs*, genauso wie *im* die Kurzform für *in dem* ist. Das *'s* ist eine Kurzform für *es*: *Wie geht's? Was gibt's? Ich glaube, gleich knallt's*.

Comment: Das ist keineswegs ein Trost oder eine Rechtfertigung! Dein Kommentar widerspiegelt eben diese sorglose Einstellung, von der ich rede!  (Nichts für Ungut! ^^ )

Comment: @BarthZalewski: Was "schöner" ist oder nicht, lässt sich wohl kaum generell festlegen. Dazu kommt das Bedürfnis in vielen Textformen, exakte Wortwiederholungen möglichst zu vermeiden. "bzw." und "und" haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen und sind somit nicht gegeneinander austauschbar. Und dass *'s* ausschließlich eine Abkürzung von *es* sein soll, halte ich für eine falsche Annahme. Verkürzt man die Vorkommen von *das* im Ausdruck "das Große und das Kleine", wie es im gesprochenen Deutsch mitunter vorkommt, würde man das wohl auch "'s Große und's Kleine" schreiben. Die ...

Comment: ... Auslassung des Apostrophs ist nur bei besonders häufigen Verschmelzungen zulässig.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das mit dem Apostroph ist nicht richtig. Er _muß_ bei Auslassungen gesetzt werden (§ 96 (2)), wenn Wörter sonst „schwer lesbar oder missverständlich“ sind, und _kann_ gesetzt werden (§ 97), „wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind“. Beides sind nicht gerade eindeutige Kriterien; aber von Häufigkeit ist nicht die Rede, sondern bei einer seltenen, aber völlig offensichtlichen Auslassung braucht man keinen Apostroph zu setzen.

Comment: chirlu: Ebenso heißt es: ["Bei den allgemein üblichen Verschmelzungen von Präposition (Verhältniswort) und Artikel setzt man in der Regel keinen Apostroph."](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph). Ich sehe schon einen Zusammenhang zwischen "allgemein üblich" und der Häufigkeit, und genauso hängt meiner Meinung nach auch die empfundene Schwierigkeit des Lesens davon ab, wie häufig man der betreffenden Verkürzung begegnet. Aber es ist richtig, dass die Regel nicht explizit an die Häufigkeit gebunden ist. (Das ändert freilich nicht meine Kernaussage bezüglich *'s*.)

Comment: Sprache funktioniert nicht nach Angebot und Nachfrage. Wenn meine Universität sich in Spreizsprache präsentiert, dann hat sie ein lokales Monopol und ich kann mir keine andere Präsentation der Uni aussuchen. Es gibt keinen Wettbewerb. Wenn im Supermarkt der "Kartoffel Pürree" am billigsten ist werde ich der Sprache wegen nicht zu einem anderen greifen. Dass man in der Werbung mit Deppenleerzeichen noch auffällt glaube ich kaum. Was ist mit "künstlich" (i.d. Werbung) gemeint und wieso in Anführungsstrichen? Wieso bei Sender, Empfänger usw.? Außerhalb der Schweiz übrigens "Fuß", nicht "Fuss".

Comment: Außerdem wirkt der Verweis auf Luther schwach, denn wer sagt denn, dass Luther begabt darin gewesen wäre, das Werkzeug Sprache souverän zu meistern? Viele Regeln, etwa zur Zusammenschreibung oder zur Verwendung des Apostrophs (u. von Anführungszeichen) haben einen klaren Sinn und wurden im Laufe der Jahre entwickelt/gefunden. Deppen Leer Zeichen erschweren das Lesen objektiv. Welchen Sinn hat es, das Werkzeug mutwillig zu zerstören oder verrosten zu lassen?

Comment: @userunknown - Natürlich funktioniert sie so. Sie funktioniert nicht nach Gesetzgebung und auch nicht weil "irgendjemand bestimmt, was richtig ist".   Sprachwissenschaft ist beobachtende Wissenschaft, und wenn genug Leute die Sprache "falsch" benutzen, wird das eben "richtig". Luther als "Erfinder" einer gemeinsamen deutschen Sprache das Meistern ebendieser absprechen zu wollen, ist allerdings ein starkes Stück...

Comment: @tofro: Luther hat Redewendungen geprägt, nicht Grammatik oder Rechtschreibung. Und dass es Angebot und Nachfrage nicht sind habe ich ja dargelegt. Auch bei Nachrichten habe ich mehr als nur die Kategorie Sprache, nach der in Angebote auswähle, da ist die Sprache fest verkoppelt und ich frage sie notgedrungen mit nach.

Comment: @userunknown Du scheinst dich nicht überzeugen zu lassen wollen - Bei dir bewerben sich zwei Menschen, der eine kriegt keinen graden Satz raus, und seine Bewerbung strotzt vor Rechtschreibfehlern, der andere kann reden und seine Bewerbung ist in gutem Deutsch abgefasst - Sonst sind beide gleich. Wen stellst du ein?

Comment: @tofro: Du verwechselst hier, wer sich für welche Aussage rechtfertigen muss. Du hast allgemein behauptet "Sprache funktioniert ganz klar nach dem Prinzip von Angebot und Nachfrage …" - das kannst Du nicht mit einem Beispiel, wo es tatsächlich so ist, belegen. Man kann solche Allgemeinaussagen aber mit einem Gegenbeispiel widerlegen. Ich hab' noch eins: Wieviele Leute lehnen die AGB von Facebook ab, weil zu klein geschrieben, in hell auf dunkelgrau, zu lang, inhaltlich eine Zumutung, in schlechtem Deutsch? Zu wieviel Prozent wird schlechtes Deutsch in die Quote eingehen? Woher weiß FB das?